# ARCore – Rendering objects 200m far from camera

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm working on Android AR project using ARCore and Sceneform. I need to place the objects **from 30 meters to 200 meters far** from user's camera and faced with the **frustum culling** issue in ArCore, described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901044/2515701).

I'm trying to set **projection matrix** to increase the `far` parameter using this method

```
public void getProjectionMatrix (float[] dest, 
                                 int offset, 
                                 float near, 
                                 float far);
```

But I can't find possibility to set the rendering projection matrix.

Here is my code:

```
arFragment.arSceneView.apply {
    scene.addOnUpdateListener {
        // Some code to return from this callback if arFrame is not initialised yet
        if (!objectsAdded) {
            placeObject(Pose.makeTranslation(0f, 100f, 100f), this)
            objectsAdded = true
            scene.camera.projectionMatrix = Matrix(computeProjectionMatrix(frame.camera))
            // P.S. frame.camera is ArCore's camera, scene.camera is Sceneform's one.
            // So, I'm not sure that using them in such way is consistent  
        }
    }
}
```

`setProjectionMatrix` method contains annotation `VisibleForTesting`. So, I'm not sure if I should use it and there is a guarantee that it will work.

Please, advice if I can do it in some other way?
If no, what the best way to do far placed objects visible for user?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not really supported according to this: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/498

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to setup ARCamera's `far clipping plane` and `near clipping plane` in ARCore itself. You can only do it in your current **rendering framework** (Google Sceneform is officially deprecated, remember?) using corresponding settings.

Answer (score 2):

Using Sceneform, you can set the far clip plane like this: `arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera().setFarClipPlane(…);`

Comment: this should be the selected answer